# Using EmberJS in Grails project with a layout

Tags: javascript, grails, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use Ember in my grails project. However, I'm having a layout issue. The ember templates are always displaying below the footer. This does not happen with regular html, when I don't use Ember.

Here is my layout

```
<html>
 <head>
   <g:layoutHead/>
   <r:require module="application"/>
 </head>

<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <g:layoutBody/>
    <div id="push"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer>
  </div>
  </r:layoutResources/>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the page where I'm using ember template

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
     <h1>test</h1>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my applicationresources.groovy

```
modules = {
    application {
        dependsOn "jquery", "emberjs","emberjsdata"
        resource url:'js/application.js'
        resource url:'js/App.js'
    }

    emberjs {
        dependsOn 'jquery,handlebars'
        resource url: 'js/ember-latest-stable.js'
    }
    handlebars {
        resource url: 'js/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.4.js'
    }
    emberjsdata{
        dependsOn 'emberjs'
        resource url: 'js/ember-data-latest.js'
    }
 }
```

**Problem**

For some reason the `hello` shows up below the footer. Not sure why since it works fine with plain html

Comment: Are you trying to make a single page application, using grails rest like? Or you want to use the gsp's rendered by grails, but in some page use an embedded ember application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default ember use the `body` as root element, then the contents of templates will be inserted and replaced in that element. So by default ember is a single page application.

If you need ember just for some piece of html, use by example:

Javacript

```
YourAppNamespace.rootElement = "#myEmberApp";
```

Html

```
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <!-- render normally contents from server -->
    <g:layoutBody/>        
  </div>
  <div id="myEmberApp">
    <!-- all content here is controlled by ember -->
  </div>
  <div id="footer>
    My company all rights reserved
  </div>
  </r:layoutResources/>
</body>
```

Hope it helps